# How does the "curious" badge work (conditions to be earned)?

Tags: support, badges

By reading the description of the conditions needed to earn the **Curious** (or *Inquisitive* or *Socratic*) badge on the Help Center, it is still quite unclear to me what conditions are needed to earn it.

I even checked the profiles of users who earned them, but I wasn't able to deduce how it works.

Could somebody clarify or explain it to me, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Curious you need to ask 5 questions on 5 separate days which have a positive score. For Inquisitive, the number of question and days is 30 and for Socratic they are 100.

You wouldn't receive the Curious badge if you asked 5 questions in the space of 1 hour. The badges are to gauge if you are returning to the site and continuing to ask questions day-by-day.

Comment: The questions must also be "Well Received", i.e. not downvoted.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399

Comment: For Curious, does it mean 1 question a days for 5 days, or can it be 2 questions the 1st day and 3 the 5th ?